# Limitar el tamaño de un TextField en javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Quiero limitar la cantidad de caracteres que admite un control `TextField` y he probado con este método:

```
    public static void fijarTamañoMáximo(final TextField campoTexto, final int tamañoMáximo) {
        campoTexto.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, final String valorAnterior, final String valorActual) {

                Pattern permitido = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-zÑÇÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÏÜÂÊÎÔÛñçáéíóúàèìòùïüâêîôû]");
                Matcher mpermitido = permitido.matcher(valorActual.substring(valorActual.length() - 1));

                if (mpermitido.find()) {
                    if (campoTexto.getText().length() > tamañoMáximo) {
                        String s = campoTexto.getText().substring(0, tamañoMáximo);
                        campoTexto.setText(s);
                    }
                } else // caracter no permitido, borrarlo
                if (valorActual.length() == 1) {
                    campoTexto.setText(""); // ¿Por qué sale error?
                } else {
                    campoTexto.setText(valorAnterior);
                }
            }
        });
   }

fijarTamañoMáximo(miTextField, 10); // limito a 10 caracteres
```

También limito el tipo de datos a caracteres alfabéticos. Hasta aquí todo funciona bien (aunque admito sugerencias para mejorarlo).
El problema es que cuando se teclea el primer carácter como uno no permitido, por ejemplo un número, sale un error cuando pongo el texto del `TextField` a "" con `campoTexto.setText("");`. Lo mismo sucede si intento borrar el único carácter del control y no sé por qué.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El error ocurre porque cuando se teclea un carácter no permitido siendo la longitud del `TextField` 0 en la declaración del `Matcher` se intenta asignar una substring(-1).
Por otra parte, cuando se asigna el texto "" al `TextField` se provoca una rellanada automática del Listener que vuelve a encontrar el mismo error del principio.
La solución es no aplicar el `Pattern` si no se ha añadido nada al `TextField`:

```
public static void fijarTamañoMáximo(final TextField campoTexto, final int tamañoMáximo) {
    campoTexto.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, final String valorAnterior, final String valorActual) {

            if (valorActual.length() > valorAnterior.length()) {
                Pattern permitido = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-zÑÇÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÏÜÂÊÎÔÛñçáéíóúàèìòùïüâêîôû]");
                Matcher mpermitido = permitido.matcher(valorActual.substring(valorAnterior.length()));

                if (!mpermitido.find()) {
                    // caracter no permitido, borrarlo
                    campoTexto.setText(valorAnterior);
                    return;
                }
                if (campoTexto.getText().length() > tamañoMáximo) {
                    campoTexto.setText(campoTexto.getText().substring(0, tamañoMáximo));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Para el que prefiera utilizar `lengthProperty`:

```
public static void fijarTamañoMáximo(final TextField campoTexto, final int tamañoMáximo) {
    campoTexto.lengthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
            Number valorAnterior, Number valorActual) {          

            if (valorActual.intValue() > valorAnterior.intValue()) {
                Pattern permitido = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-zÑÇÁÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÏÜÂÊÎÔÛñçáéíóúàèìòùïüâêîôû]");            
                Matcher mpermitido = permitido.matcher(campoTexto.getText().substring(valorAnterior.intValue()));

                if (!mpermitido.find()) {
                    // caracter no permitido, borrarlo                       
                    campoTexto.setText(campoTexto.getText().substring(0, valorAnterior.intValue()));
                    return;                    
                }

                // Revisa que la longitud del texto no sea mayor a la variable definida.
                if (campoTexto.getText().length() >= tamañoMáximo) {
                    campoTexto.setText(campoTexto.getText().substring(0, tamañoMáximo));
                }                   
            }               
        }
    });
}
```

Solución un poquito más larga pero igual de efectiva.

Answer (score 0):

Usa:
 `campoTexto.lengthProperty()`

en lugar de :

```
campoTexto.textProperty()
```

y usa el mismo listener, `ChangeListener` para realizar la validación de la cantidad de caracteres permitidos.

Ejemplo:

```
public static void fijarTamanoMaximo(final TextField campoTexto, final int tamanoMaximo) {

         campoTexto.lengthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                    Number valorAnterior, Number valorActual) {
                if (valorActual.intValue() > valorAnterior.intValue()) {
                    // Revisa que la longitud del texto no sea mayor a la variable definida.
                    if (campoTexto.getText().length() >= tamanoMaximo) {
                        campoTexto.setText(campoTexto.getText().substring(0, tamanoMaximo));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

   }
```

de esta forma podemos validar nuestro `TextField`, `CustomTextField`, etc, para evitar se ingresen, mas de cierto numero de caracteres.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. La verdad es que cambiar el método textProperty por lengthProperty ni añade ni quita nada. Con tu solución he implementado el control de lo que se introduce por el teclado mediante Pattern y vuelvo a encontrarme exactamente el mismo error ya que dicho error viene provocado precisamente por esta implementación.

Comment: Nadie ha dicho que cambiar los métodos  textProperty por lengthProperty añade ni quita nada. Simplemente se agrega un listener para tu mismo implementar la validación cuando ocurre un cambio en la longitud del texto dentro de TextField.

Comment: No se cuanto tiempo uses Java, pero este es el método más común para "Limitar el tamaño de un TextField en javaFX".

Answer (score 0):

El problema que he encontrado en las respuestas anteriores es que si el carácter ilegal se introduce al principio o en medio de la cadena entonces no funciona y deja introducir el carácter erróneo. Para solucionarlo podemos recorrer todos los caracteres de la nueva cadena y comprobar uno a uno si cumple con el filtro:

```
campoTexto.textProperty().addListener((final ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, final String valorAnterior, final String valorActual) -> {

    if (valorActual.length() > valorAnterior.length()) {

        Pattern permitido = Pattern.compile("[\\d]"); // filtro sólo números
        Matcher mpermitido;

        // recorremos la cadena buscando carácteres no deseados               
        for (int i = 0; i < valorActual.length(); i++) {                  
            mpermitido = permitido.matcher(valorActual.substring(i, i + 1));
            if (!mpermitido.find()) {
                campoTexto.setText(valorAnterior);
                return;
            }
        }
        // controlamos la longitud máxima...            
        if (decimales.getText().length() > longitudMáxima) {
            decimales.setText(decimales.getText().substring(0, longitudMáxima));
        }               
    }
});
```